# Slowing down the read rate of android Ontouchlistener

Tags: android, touch, delay

I am attempting my first game using a custom view extended from view that ,as it stands, is just a background image that can pan by dragging with the ACTION_Move.

It also has a zoom image that gets drawn on the canvas and when an ACTION_UP occurs on this region, a zoom in is registered and the image is scaled up.

The problem I now experience is that although the drag works well with the ontouch function returning true, the ACTION_UP is very sensitive and a single touch executes the code in the ACTION_UP case statement a few hundred times.  Instead of just incrementing the zoom up by 10% it rapidly zooms to 100%.

If I return false to the function, the zoom works normally by 10% per touch but as stated in previous posts, the function must return true for ACTION_MOVE to respond.

Things I've tried

1. Thread.sleep() - it does exactly the same thing by incrementing the zoom 100 times with a delay in between.
2. Changing the returned value in the case statements so it returns true only for ACTION_MOVE but move does not respond.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()`  - only use this if you **really** understand what it does, and never on the main thread.  Without seeing your code, we don't know what the bug is.  The ACTION_UP is neither sensitive nor insensitive.  It is merely an event raised when the pointer leaves the screen.

Comment: ACTION_UP should not act the way you describe it. If you use a `switch` statement to handle the different actions, make sure you put in a `break` after each switch case.

Comment: You need to post your code in order to provide you with an accurate answer

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  It was a case of a missing break; in the case statements and just like that it was fixed.  If you would post it as an answer I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a boolean variable to control the zoom, for example:

```
private boolean zoom = true;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

// ACTION_UP
if(zoom) {
    doZoom();
    zoom = false;
}
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        zoom = true;
    }
}, 100); // Delay 100 ms, adjust for ideal zoom speed
```

Now it won't zoom again until the 100ms delay is completed.

Comment: This looks like a hacky workaround to me.  If the OPs code is being run "a few hundred times", then there is a bug in their code.  All this does is prevent the effects of the bug.

Comment: @Simon Indeed perhaps, but as previously stated without seeing OP's code it's not possible to provide an accurate solution.